# use of Ipython 2.7 und 3.4 parallel on windows 7 Anaconda 2.2 32-bit

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, python-3.4, anaconda, conda

I have installed on my W7 a `32-bit` version of `Anaconda 2.2` with default environment `Python 2.7.9`, all works fine.
After update with

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

the environment of 2.7 is still working.

It is also possible to switch with `activate py34` oder `deactivate` and get a working python version of 2.7 or 3.4 with the python command - but when I start `ipython` or `ipython notebook` I still get only the 2.7 environment.

I had looked with `env` into the environment variables and it seems the activate command only changes the `PATH` variable and append in front the

```
[usrs]\Anaconda\envs\py34 and [usrs]\Anaconda\envs\Scripts.
```

And changes of course the prompt variable.
I can't see no Python variable or other which can tell the (old 2.7) IPython interpreter under `[usrs]\Anaconda\Scripts` to switch to 3.4 and there is no new one under the changed path.
Any suggestions?
Under Lubuntu all works fine. But there the "conda create" command had installed an separate ipython script in ~/anaconda/envs/py34/bin.

Comment: In Windows there should also be files for the IPython commands in `...\Anaconda\envs\py34\Scripts\`. When you activate the py34 env, that location should be added to PATH, so it should find things there first.

Comment: Yes there are, but only
 2to3-script.py 2to3.exe, easy_install-script.py, easy_install.exe, easy_install.exe.manifest, idle-script.py,idle.exe,pip-script.py
pip.exe, pydoc-script.py,pydoc.exe
and no ipython.exe or what ever.

Comment: That sounds like you don't have IPython installed in that env. With the env active, try `conda install ipython ipython-notebook`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, that was the mistake. I was spoiled by the silent installation on Lubuntu.

Comment: If you passed it `anaconda` when creating the env, it *should* have installed IPython as well (anaconda depends on ipython). But it looks like it didn't, for whatever reason.